# Unlocking FileVault encrypted drive from Terminal (to allow pasting password)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, filevault

I have a long, complicated password for an external drive encrypted with FileVault that I have securely stored, but OS X doesn’t allow pasting into the password unlock GUI dialog (argh!). How can I unlock it via the terminal so I can paste the password in there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beginning with OS X 10.11 “El Capitan”, you can now paste into the GUI unlock dialog! If you’re using an older OS X (or just want to use the command-line to unlock), read on.

---

The [`diskutil`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html) command is for working with volumes via the terminal in OS X.

- First, find the UUID for your drive via `diskutil list`. You should see a section like this:

  ```
  Logical Volume MyAwesomeDrive on disk2s2
  96EC217A-54F2-49A3-8471-9BFE535D159A
  Locked Encrypted
  ```

  Where “MyAwesomeDrive” is the volume name, and “96EC217A-54F2-49A3-8471-9BFE535D159A” is the UUID we’re looking for.
- Run `diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume <uuid>`, replacing `<uuid>` with the UUID found above. It will prompt for your password (which can be pasted in) and unlock the encrypted volume.

<sub>Note: If you’re typing/pasting passwords or other secure information into the terminal, it would be wise to enable “Secure Keyboard Entry” in the Terminal app menu (also available in iTerm). [Read more on security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47749/how-secure-is-secure-keyboard-entry-in-mac-os-xs-terminal).</sub>